# Ratio of first two moments of sample covariance eigenvalues

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, covariance

Suppose we form $X$ by stacking $b$ examples drawn from some distribution in $n$ dimensions as rows and look at $\{\lambda_i\}$, the eigenvalues of $\Sigma=X^TX$. Consider the following random quantity:

$$r_b=\frac{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)^2}{\text{Tr} \Sigma^2} = \frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\ldots+\lambda_n)^2}{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\ldots+\lambda_n^2} $$

As we vary $b$, expectation of this quantity seems to interpolate as weighed harmonic mean of $E[r_1]$ and $E[r_\infty]$. Can someone help me understand where the harmonic mean comes from?

More specifically, the relationship between expectations of $r_b,r_1,r_\infty$ seems to be:

$$\frac{b}{r_b}\le \frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{b-1}{r_\infty}$$

---

Using Gaussian random variable, the fit is almost perfect

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/mo-expected-drop.nb)

Using highly non-Gaussian distribution, it seems bounded below

[image]

Motivation: this quantity gives the expected decrease in squared error after a single step of randomly initialized least-squares stochastic gradient descent with batch size $b$

Comment: Could you please clarify your notation?  Since $\lambda$ is a "list," what kinds of mathematical objects are meant by "$E(\lambda)^2$" and "$E\lambda^2$"??

Comment: updated with clarification

Comment: Do $n$ and $b$ refer to the same quantity?  I suspect not because then $r_1=1$ automatically; but then how are $n$ and $b$ related?

Comment: They are different. Phrased another way, the question is how $E[Tr(\Sigma)^2/Tr(\Sigma^2)]$ depends on b, where $\Sigma$ is sample second moment matrix formed from $b$ examples